# Docker ASPNET Core project build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-7.0

I have used the following 3 docker files to build my ASP.NET Core 7.0 web app for around 6 months without an issue on my iMac Pro using the latest OS version with all upgraded software running Docker Desktop for MAC.

**Step 1:** I build an ASP.NET Core 7.0 SDK using:

```
ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
FROM $REPO:7.0.7-jammy-amd64

ENV \
    # Unset ASPNETCORE_URLS from aspnet base image
    ASPNETCORE_URLS= \
    # Do not generate certificate
    DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false \
    # Do not show first run text
    DOTNET_NOLOGO=true \
    # SDK version
    DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=7.0.304 \
    # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true \
    # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip \
    # PowerShell telemetry for docker image usage
    POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetSDK-Ubuntu-22.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        git \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install .NET SDK
RUN curl -fSL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && dotnet_sha512='f4b7d0cde432bd37f445363b3937ad483e5006794886941e43124de051475925b3cd11313b73d2cae481ee9b8f131394df0873451f6088ffdbe73f150b1ed727' \
    && echo "$dotnet_sha512  dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -oxzf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./packs ./sdk ./sdk-manifests ./templates ./LICENSE.txt ./ThirdPartyNotices.txt \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    # Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
    && dotnet help

# Install PowerShell global tool
RUN powershell_version=7.3.4 \
    && curl -fSL --output PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg https://pwshtool.blob.core.windows.net/tool/$powershell_version/PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg \
    && powershell_sha512='8f48ec8b99eade6179792dfd398aa5e73d347050f21d76438c005f08c3fbaab9e15cf17e7da563790f3f072c40608bf0730c5cfeee95ac97fbbfd8a9dc1e4c4d' \
    && echo "$powershell_sha512  PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/powershell \
    && dotnet tool install --add-source / --tool-path /usr/share/powershell --version $powershell_version PowerShell.Linux.x64 \
    && dotnet nuget locals all --clear \
    && rm PowerShell.Linux.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg \
    && ln -s /usr/share/powershell/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh \
    && chmod 755 /usr/share/powershell/pwsh \
    # To reduce image size, remove the copy nupkg that nuget keeps.
    && find /usr/share/powershell -print | grep -i '.*[.]nupkg$' | xargs rm
```

Then in the terminal run:
docker build -f ./Docker/Initial_Setup_Base_Images/Dockerfile-aspnetcore-sdk7.0-base -t aspnetcore7_sdk .

**Step 2:** then build an ASP.NET Core 7.0.7 runtime image using:

```
ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime

# Installer image
FROM amd64/buildpack-deps:jammy-curl AS installer

# Retrieve ASP.NET Core
RUN aspnetcore_version=7.0.7 \
    && curl -fSL --output aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$aspnetcore_version/aspnetcore-runtime-$aspnetcore_version-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='e56ee9bc458214bce461e9688e5229ba5b69046ec38a27bfdb2b5413d4b41500cca40152d182793c2768318719d97980b62ae9724de75d6d02874c25e938374d' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && tar -oxzf aspnetcore.tar.gz ./shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz


# ASP.NET Core image
FROM $REPO:7.0.7-jammy-amd64

# ASP.NET Core version
ENV ASPNET_VERSION=7.0.7

COPY --from=installer ["/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App", "/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"]
```

Then in the terminal run:

```
docker build -f ./Docker/Initial_Setup_Base_Images/Dockerfile-aspnetcore7.0-base -t aspnetcore7 .
```

**Step 3:** at this point, in my docker desktop for MAC I have the ASP.NET Core Runtime and SDK Image so I then try to build my Visual Studio Project which is using NETCore.App 7.0.7 with the following command:

```
FROM aspnetcore7_sdk:latest AS build-env
ARG Configuration=Release

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish Code/AMS_WebUI/AMS_Portal/AMS.Portal.Server.Web/AMS.Portal.Server.Web.csproj -c Release -o AMS.Portal.Server.Web/out

FROM aspnetcore7:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/AMS.Portal.Server.Web/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AMS.Portal.Server.Web.dll"]
```

Then in the terminal run:
docker build -f ./Docker/Generated/Build/DockerfileBuildBaseImage-AMS.Portal.Server.Web -t ams_portal_server .

All the above has worked for over 6 months but after upgrading to the new Visual Studio and the new ASP.NET Core 7.0.7 I get the following error:

```
------
DockerfileBuildBaseImage-AMS.Portal.Server.Web:34
--------------------
  32 |     
  33 |     COPY . ./
  34 | >>> RUN dotnet publish Code/AMS_WebUI/AMS_Portal/AMS.Portal.Server.Web/AMS.Portal.Server.Web.csproj -c Release -o AMS.Portal.Server.Web/out
  35 |     
  36 |     FROM aspnetcore7:latest
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet publish Code/AMS_WebUI/AMS_Portal/AMS.Portal.Server.Web/AMS.Portal.Server.Web.csproj -c Release -o AMS.Portal.Server.Web/out" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I dont see any errors in the terminal only code warnings like warning BL0005: Component parameter 'Expanded' should not be set outside of its component. which I understand why but this should not stop the build.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

TIA

James